# Best way to copy python environment of Google colab

Tags: installation, anaconda, google-colaboratory, virtual-environment

I have a code which was developed on Google colab and now I want to run it on local machine or on a server. The problem is my code has got a lot of dependencies and its getting difficult to prepare an virtual / conda environment. The code is working perfectly on colab. So is there any way so that I can have an image of that environment so its easier for me to run it wherever I want

Answer (score 11):

You can run this command: `!pip freeze` and you will get all packages installed and their versions:

[image]

you can copy paste this to your local machine into a `requirements.txt`, or you can download this file with this commands:

1. Execute in one cell `!pip freeze >> requirements.txt`
2. Go to the left panel : [image]
3. Right click on file created, and select download

[image]

the last step is create the environment, yoy can use `conda` or `virtenv`. Use `pip` with this command: `pip install -r requirements.txt`